# モバイル表示の時、検索欄の「キャンセル」が改行されてしまっている

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

[image: Cancel]

改行されない方がよい

Answer (score 1):

現在、検索欄のキャンセルボタンは無くなっています。モバイル環境でも同様です。おそらく[2018年のレスポンシブデザイン採用](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2783/3054)のタイミングで変わったものと思います。

> [image: スクリーンショット]